# Automatic Migration and manual invocation of Update-Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6, automatic-migration

Do I have to manually issue the `Update-Database` command in the package manager console even though I have automatic migrations turned on?

I'm running MVC4 and EF6. The solution is targeted for .NET 4 (I can't change this unfortunately).

**EDIT**: I'm aware of the difference between Code Migrations that would require me to properly seed existing tables. This question is more based towards a scenario where I add a table that has no relations, which I would think would just run?

**EDIT 2**: Table that should be added automatically

============

**New Table definition**

```
public class InboundFile : Entity
{
    [Required]
    public String FilePath { get; set; }
}
```

**EF Config file**

```
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
        MigrationsDirectory = @"Migrations";
    }

    protected override void Seed(Unifi.Context.DBContext context)
    {
        context.InboundFiles.AddOrUpdate(
            x => x.FilePath,
            new InboundFile { CreateDate = DateTime.Now, ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now, FilePath = "c:/test", IsDeleted = false }
        );
    }
```

**DB Context**

public class DBContext : DbContext
    {

```
    public DBContext()
        : base("MyConn")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public DbSet<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Region> Regions { get; set; }

    public DbSet<InboundFile> InboundFiles { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try placing this in your Application_Start

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DbContext, Configuration>);
using (var temp = new DbContext()) {
    temp.Database.Initialize(true);
}
```

This will force it to run `update-database`, and in doing so `seed`, every time your application starts.

Answer (score 0):

`Update-Database` triggers an "*update*" operation. You can run your app and database will be updated on app start.

I prefer to run `Update-Database` manually because I can see if there are any db migration errors.

Comment: Right, So that is where I'm getting a little confused. I added another table to my context, no relations so nothing to worry about error wise, then ran the application. What's weird to me is that the table was not added to my database even though I have auto-migrations turned on. What gets weirder is that I then manually issued `Update-Database` and it found and ran an automatic migration.

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters or not, but I have the web and context in different projects as part of the solution whole.

Comment: Could you please share new code for your table. I'd like to see changes in db context and entity class itself.

Comment: Where is DbContext itself?

Comment: Didn't think that was relevant, but I added it.